# Pass information to a canvas element that will be returned when it is clicked

Tags: html, canvas

Is there a way to pass some id or information to an canvas element so that when you click on it you can retrieve it back?

Comment: Just register click events on the canvas and detect coordinates. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you have a lot of elements you're trying to detect clicks on it's likely you should be using SVG instead of canvas.

Comment: you can detect coordinates and know what is draw at that spot, but it doesn't gives you some kind of id where you can tie it back to your data model to do something useful.

Comment: Yes, for that sort of thing use SVG.  Then each drawn element is an object in the DOM which you can attach normal click handlers to.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you to take a look to [**Kinetic.js**](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/) an object oriented canvas library. There are other options, but from the ones I've tried until now this one is specially easy to integrate in a HTML5 / Canvas project (IMO) and has a great support for events (click, mouseOver, mouseOut... etc.) and also for Drag & Drop. Great to use in user-interaction-oriented canvases.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid that you may not select `canvas` element just like selecting HTML DOM element by id or class. But you still can add mouse event listeners to detect the coordinates. And I still think using HTML button tag is much better.

Here's a tutorial about it http://simonsarris.com/blog/140-canvas-moving-selectable-shapes.

Hopefully, it can give you help.

Comment: I was looking at that example. It seemed very inefficient, since you possibly have to draw every element onto the ghost canvas to detect which element you're clicking on.

Comment: Yes.But  I think you can try html elements (<button> or <div> ...) as  buttons and position these elements into canvas area by CSS.It will more efficient and more easily to code.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use the mousedown listner and then specify the area of the button, e.g here the button would be from (30,30) to (60,60)

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
function doMouseDown(event) {
  x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
  if (x>=30 && x<=60 && y>=30 && y<=60) {
     alert("BUTTON PRESSED")
  }
}
```

This is probably the easiest method without importing any libraries

Answer (score 1):

I have made buttons in canvas many times. By using this mouse event handler for canvas

```js
function getPosition(event) {
    var x,
        y;
    if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined) {
        x = event.x;
        y = event.y;
    } else {
        x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    x -= canvasElement.offsetLeft;
    y -= canvasElement.offsetTop;
    x = x - window.pageXOffset;
    y = y - window.pageYOffset;
    mouseX = x;
    mouseY = y;
}
```

getPosition should be used/called by the canvas like this:

```html
<canvas onclick='getPosition(event);'></canvas>
```

It also works for mouseover and mousemove.

So by using mouseX and Y you can check if the mouse is on the button. The button has to be rectangular.

```js
if (mouseX > buttonX && 
    mouseX < buttonX + buttonWidth && 
    mouseY > buttonY && 
    mouseY < buttonY + buttonHeight) {
    //The mouse is on the button!  
}
```

buttonX and Y are referring to the top left corner of the button/area. Similar to ctx.fillRect()